# How To Replicate 2 Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, webserver

> **I want to replicate 2 Ubuntu Server . So if i change settings on one server it will replicate to other .**
>
> The Server Will be Running Zpanel ( mysql , bind , apache , postfix , etc ) ..

### Updated

The **server 2** is exact the same copy of **Server 1** . Basically after installing & updating **server 1** i have made **clone of server 1** . I am using Vmware Workstation for testing .

### Update

if i update DB or something like update in /var/www/ on 1st server it automatically update on 2nd server ....... what i really want is ... i have 2 servers ..that will be Web hosting Servers ( Zpanel) i want Replication on 2 identical server if one is down 2nd one will be up as it an replica of 1st

Comment: Posting as a comment since you'd still have to adapt the answer, but have you seen [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/272183/clone-ubuntu-server-setup-to-many-machines) over on Server Fault?

Comment: Are these identical servers?

Comment: yes it is ......100 %

Comment: Are they going to be in the same location or different locations?

Comment: on same location

Comment: Using both Chef and Rsync would be a possible solution

Comment: Would be helpful if you describe a little bit more what you expect. Do you want: 1. a third server who keeps your servers in sync 2. two server who sync decentralised via ssh 3. A specialised tool which keep the servers secure and decentralised in sync…

Comment: yes ..... .. ( what i have in mind example ) if i update DB or something like update in /var/www/ on 1st server it automatically update on 2nd server ....... what i really want is  ... i have 2 servers ..that will be Web hosting Servers          ( Zpanel)  i want Replication on 2 identical server if one is down 2nd one will be up as it an replica of 1st .. ......

Comment: See, on one hand you say you want only settings to be replicated, no data, but then you say "var/www or DB" should be updated -- THAT is data, not settings. So which do you want? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### What is Web server replication?
>
> Replicating a web server machine is
> the process of synchronizing two or more machines, so that they each
> have the exact same files, at any given point in time.
>
> #### Benefits of Web server replication
>
> There are two primary benefits to web server replication:
>
> 1. High availability
> 2. Performance during high load times
>
> #### Rsync
>
> Rsync is a Linux shell utility that supports efficient copying of data
> between two servers.
>
> Unlike "normal copy" - Rsync only copies differential data (what just
> got changed, instead of all the files). Another benefit of Rsync is
> that it copies over SSH - so data is encrypted across the channel.
>
> Rsync is one of the most popular methods to replicate web servers.
> It's reliable, easy to setup and fast.
>
> This guide,  will walk you through the process of using Rsync to
> replicate two web server machines.
>
> #### Below are the needed setup steps
>
> 1. Install RSync
> 2. Select folder(s) to replicate
> 3. Create Rsync server config file
> 4. Installing & Running Rsync server
> 5. Fetching changes with the Rsync client
> 6. Setting Rsync client as a cronjob <sup>1</sup>

[Read More](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-replicating-web-servers-using-rsync-1736.html)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source: [SPI](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-replicating-web-servers-using-rsync-1736.html)</sup>

Comment: its not what i want ...but its is the closest one ...& ty

Answer (score -1):

You could use `rsync`. [Keep 2 servers in sync with rsync and ssh](http://linux-101.org/howto/keep-2-servers-sync-rsync-and-ssh)

Comment: this is not an answer to my question

Answer (score -1):

I think you are searching for something like [DRBD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRBD). There might be also alternatives available, but this is certainly a good starting point to search for a solution for your use case.

Comment: tested ......... Drbd , glusterfs ....

Comment: @OneZero and it does not satisfy your needs?

Comment: i dont want to replicate data ... i want to replicate ubuntu server .. hope you will now understand

Comment: @OneZero Ah ok. Not as a backup system, but in order to have two different, but equal servers? Maybe you should edit your question and clarify what needs to be synchronized and what not.